# PYTHON 3: Subtraction of 2 HH:MM:SS string array members

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 `str` arrays, objects in are times formatted like HH:MM:SS. I am trying to do the subtraction of the corresponding members of the arrays.

`difference[i]=time2[i]-time1[i]`

I don't know what format to convert the `str` arrays to.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: Use datetime.strptime  Stack Overflow has a lot of examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it into datetime (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/).

```
import pendulum
difference[i]= pendulum.parse(time2[i]).diff(time1[i]).in_hours()
```

Answer (score -1):

This should save it in difference as integer, if you want to have it in string as well, then just add everything after "=" into str()

```
difference[i] = int(time2[i]) - int(time1[i])
```

Comment: Converting them to int may not work. They are strings and they have : in them